# how to develop a statistical model to identify problem process in a peoplesoft system, the model should give recent run more weight over old run

Tags: plsql, peoplesoft

below query only give minor difference between weighted average and normal average, what should be good model and how to get probability of job failing in peoplesoft

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(SUM(ntile1) over(partition BY prcsname,status order by status)/SUM(ntile1) over(partition BY prcsname),2)*100 as weighted_pecentage,
 TRUNC(count(1) over(partition BY prcsname,status order by status)/count(1) over(partition BY prcsname),2)*100 as normal_percentage,
 prcsname,
 status
 FROM
 (SELECT 100-ntile(100) over (partition by prcsname order by prcsname ,prcsinstance DESC)AS ntile1,
 DECODE(runstatus,9,'Success','UnSuccess') AS status ,
 p.*
 FROM psprcsrqst p
 WHERE prcsname LIKE '%'
 ORDER BY
 prcsinstance desc, prcsname,status DESC
 ) p2 order by prcsname,
 status;
 
 !! detail
 SELECT 100-ntile(100) over (partition by prcsname order by prcsinstance desc )AS ntile1,
 DECODE(runstatus,9,'Success','UnSuccess') AS status ,
 p.*
 FROM psprcsrqst p
 WHERE prcsname LIKE '%'
 ORDER BY prcsname,
 prcsinstance desc, status DESC;
```